# Names of votes for undeletion and reopen are not localized

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, voting, localization

Names of votes for [undeletion](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/alexolut?tab=votes&sort=undelete) and [reopen](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/alexolut?tab=votes&sort=reopen) are not localized in the user profile page:

> [image: undeletion]

> [image: reopen]

Original strings already translated in transifex, but no actually used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are indeed correct; I have tweaked the offending view to include them - essentially it was falling into a "I don't recognize that, just write it out" branch rather than correctly pulling in the translation for those two.