# Review for reopen page contains non-localized word "Question"

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-reopen, localization, russian-stackoverflow

[Review for reopen page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/138825) contains non-localized word "Question" for "Revision" tab:

> [image: question]

Existing [translation](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263424?key=a97ea56b0e00b2379736ae60869ff66a) is not used here.

Comment: It seems your posting the same bug in multiple iterations. Perhaps you should take some time to have a look through the site, and report back with *all* the non-localised words you find, instead of posting a separate question for each word?

Comment: @Gnemlock sorry, if my bug reports bother you, but I think one bug should reflect one thing. When multiple unlocalized words appears in the same place, then I make a single report, as I did [recently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290422/339911). I don't have a huge one list of untranslated sentences to make one bug report for all of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That text was hardcoded, not taking the existing translation. Fixed.