# Names of votes for undeletion and reopen are not localized for mobile web

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, localization, russian-stackoverflow

Looks like the same issue as described in [Names of votes for undeletion and reopen are not localized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290422/339911) and tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) happens for mobile web:

> [image: undeletion]

> [image: reopen]

For better localization implementation we also need to [separate translations](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4679/176217) for "undeletion" and "reopen". In some cases they should be translated as verb, in other as noun.

Comment: 2 close/down-voter: this issue pertains for any localized sites, not Russian SO only!

Comment: I'm not sure why folks are voting to close this as off-topic; it's a perfectly valid bug report that pertains to any localized site. Ping me if closed and I'll reopen it.

Comment: @TimPost I think they did it because of tag [tag:russian-stackoverflow] and link to ruSO.meta, but without understanding how localization of SE sites works. Thanks for supporting me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I applied Marc's fix to the mobile view. Unfortunately, I don't think we have a way to separate the translations.

Comment: I probably misunderstand the issue about separation but isn't it simply a key for _noun and _verb? Or is the issue that in some languages you would need the _noun key and in some the _verb key at the same spot?

Comment: As far as I know it's possible to use context issue for translations. E.g. "Top questions" [refers to profile](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/104811220?key=275eee841e13888d3e21bb41dfa1aa30|refersTo%3DProfile) and same original text for [the main page](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/104811220?key=52bbeeeb93577004677050859df1afd4).

Comment: @alexolut Hmm, alright, I'll look into that. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I see how that's implemented. Yeah, an easy change to make, just need to make sure I get the right strings. :) Not gonna have time for it today, but I'll take care of it next week.

Comment: Your current fix will be applyed on rev > 27113, right? I don't see translation yet.

Comment: @alexolut I kicked off the builds, so it should be up now. Let me know?

Comment: Yep. It works now!

Comment: Hi, Adam, how about adding a context to the words? We still have an issue: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9038/176217